# ggplot2 use ..count.. to control geom_point size

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, `geom_point()` can be used with `stat = "bin2d"`, and ..count.. can be used in `aes`:

```
ggplot(data=diamonds,aes(x=carat,y=price))+
geom_point(aes(color=cut,size=..count..),stat = "bin2d")
```

However I would like to rescale ..count.. so that I can better control the size of he points, however something such as the following doesn't work.

```
ggplot(data=diamons,aes(x=carat,y=price))+
geom_point(aes(color=cut,size=scales::rescale(..count..,to=c(0.5,0.9))),stat = "bin2d")
```

[image]

My final goal is to find a better alternative to the `geom_bin2d()` or `geom_hex()` which are difficult to use to represent counts with multiple groups. So can ..count.. be used to control point size?

Comment: Maybe you meant `scales::rescale(..count.., to = c(0.5,0.9))`?

Comment: Have a look at `geom_count` which is a binned version of `geom_point`. The various `scale_size_` functions might be helpful too for adjusting the sizes.

Comment: @stefan the syntax was not correct but it doesn't seem like rescale it's working with ..count..

Comment: @AndrewGustar thanks for the suggestions but I have continous variables and need to use bins.

Comment: Hm. What you mean by not working? Just had another look. Not sure. But if you want to control the size of points then you have to do that via `scale_size...`. Otheriwse ggplot2 will set the scale.

Comment: @stefan I just meant that no matter what number you use in the rescale function the size of points is always the same.

Comment: Yep. That was my guess. Have a look at e.g. `scale_size_range`. Not 100% sure about that. But the last time I made a bubble chart I used this so set the range of bubble sizes.

Comment: Sorry. Not scale_size_range. Simply `scale_size`. `range` is the argument.